# Why aren't my images being displayed in the same row?

Tags: html, css, django

So I'm using bootstrap and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to get my images all in one row, but they are all over the place and my text isn't showing up correctly either.

**matches.html**

```
<div class="container ">
    <h2>It's a match!</h2>
    <div class = "row">

            <div class="col-4">

                 <img src="{{ user.photo.url }}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >

            </div>
            <div class="col-4">

                 <img src="{% static 'images/matching_cupid.png' %}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >

            <div class="col-4">

                 <img src="{{ match.photo.url }}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >

            </div>

    </div>
    <p>You and {{ match.username }} like each other!</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'dating_app:messages' user.id %}">Start messaging </a></p>
    <br>
    <p><a href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Keep mingling!</a></p>
```

Comment: u just forgot to add </div> for your 2nd col-4.

Comment: Thank u that worked. Put that as an answer and I'll vote it correct

Comment: done. i've repost as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repost from comment as requested.
u forgot the  in 2nd col-4.

```
<div class = "row">

        <div class="col-4">

             <img src="{{ user.photo.url }}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >

        </div>
        <div class="col-4">

             <img src="{% static 'images/matching_cupid.png' %}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">

             <img src="{{ match.photo.url }}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >

        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
    .col-4 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Where? Anywhere? In styles?

Comment: what is it supposed to do

Comment: It will put your pictures in 1 row.

Comment: turns out I was just missing a div tag and it worked... so what does this do then?

Comment: it tells your images to be in a line.

Comment: @Rez this one might work if you not using bootstrap. since you are using bootstrap (class="row"). there's no need for this display inline block.